# Making this hover animation work and for my code to be responsive

Tags: html, css

> Within my Facebook button I have set an animation to show the word "Facebook" if you hover over it. Although every time I set this in, it doesn't pop. The word "Facebook" has to show to the right if you hover over it. Also, I want my code to be responsive based on the size of a device. If the phone is bigger or smaller it should be set in its size based on that. Please and thank you.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(243, 234, 234);
}

#eventcenterimg {
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#starting-info {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 32vh;
}

#starting-info2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

#phonenumber1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: green;
}

#phonenumber2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: green;
}

#address {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper .button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper .button .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1):hover .icon {
  background: #4267B2;
}

.wrapper .button .icon i {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1) span {
  color: #4267B2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    intitial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Correa Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="img/correaevent.png" height="970" alt="" id="eventcenterimg">
  <div class="correa-events-info">

    <h4 id="starting-info">Book and experience any special events at Correa's Events Center.</h4>
    <h4 id="starting-info2">Call to book at:</h4>
    <h3 id="phonenumber1"><b>720-404-2284: Victor</b></h3>
    <h3 id="phonenumber2"><b>720-292-9963: Monica</b></h3>
    <h3 id="address">Address: 3890 Kipling St. Wheat Ridge, CO, 80033</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Correas-Event-Center/100077040368594/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <span id="icontitle">Facebook</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the `.icontitle` outside the `.icon` but, still within the `.button`.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(243, 234, 234);
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper .button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper .button .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1):hover .icon {
  background: #4267B2;
}

.wrapper .button .icon i {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1) span {
  color: #4267B2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    intitial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Correa Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Correas-Event-Center/100077040368594/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
      </div>
      <span id="icontitle">Facebook</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `display` from `inline-block` to `flex` when you `hover` over `.icon`, it should be solving your problem.

```css
.wrapper .button .icon:hover {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Complete snippet

```css
body {
  background: rgb(243, 234, 234);
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper .button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

.wrapper .button .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button .icon:hover {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button:nth-child(1):hover .icon {
  background: #4267B2;
}

.wrapper .button .icon i {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper .button span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
    intitial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Correa Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="icon">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/people/Correas-Event-Center/100077040368594/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <span id="icontitle">Facebook</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```